# How do virtual drives and actual PC storage operate together?

Tags: cloud-storage, virtual-drive

Using MyCase virtual drive synced with MyCase online software, I am noticing that when I add documents to the MyCase virtual drive, it appears to allocate simultaneously in my PC's individual storage.

For example, if I transfer 1GB of data into the MyCase virtual drive, my available PC storage will decrease by 1GB. I was under the impression that the MyCase virtual drive is cloud based and has unlimited storage.

How does this work? At this rate, my actual available PC storage will be gone in no time.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Mac? Mac uses local storage, according to https://support.mycase.com/en/articles/6252205-mycase-drive-guide As they don't mention it, presumably Windows doesn't do this.

Comment: I am on Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: "No, documents are not stored locally on the computer and do not take up disc space until they are opened on a computer." - https://support.mycase.com/en/articles/6252176-mycase-drive-faqs-troubleshooting

Comment: Given that document Joep posted, have you reported this issue to the publisher for support?